# redux multiple action to just once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

I have a web app that received 20 update per second.
And I would like to dispatch it just once.
My question is how can I stored the 20 records or merge it to one object of objects.

```
response = {
   id: 123
   name: 'john'
}
response = {
   id: 456
   name: 'doe'
}
response = {
   id: 789
   name: 'foe'
}
```

Then expected result should be

```
response = {
123: {id: 123, name: 'john'},
456: {id: 456, name: 'doe'},
789: {id: 789, name: 'foe'},
}
```

and I would like to make this if the response are not more than 1 second each item.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you